# Is it possible to push an object into in an existing object's property

Tags: javascript

I want to append to this object:

```
var obj =
{
   "myKey":
   {
       "subkey": [1,2,3]
   }
};
```

this an object of additional subkeys I want to append to `obj`

```
var addKeys = {
   "subkey2" [3,4,5],
   "subkey3" [5,6,7]
}
```

I want to do something like `obj.myKey.push(addKeys);` but I know that's only for arrays. My final object should look ultimately like this:

```
var obj =
{
   "myKey":
   {
       "subkey": [1,2,3],
       "subkey2" [3,4,5],
       "subkey3" [5,6,7]
   }
};
```

Comment: Try `Object.assign(obj.myKey, addKeys)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
 var obj =
{
   "myKey":
   {
       "subkey": [1,2,3]
   }
};

var addKeys = {
   "subkey2": [3,4,5],
   "subkey3": [5,6,7]
};
 
 Object.assign(obj.myKey, addKeys)
 
 console.log(obj);
```

Object.assign will overwrite the first argument. It is called a "destructive" operation. If you want to merge objects and return a new one:

```js
 var obj =
{
   "myKey":
   {
       "subkey": [1,2,3]
   }
};

var addKeys = {
   "subkey2": [3,4,5],
   "subkey3": [5,6,7]
};
 
var merged = Object.assign({}, obj.myKey, addKeys)
 
 console.log(merged);
 console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is the right way. The old way (previous to ES2015) would involve using much more obscure data manipulation to get the same result.

Comment: Why wouldn't the second example work? It's the example from the mdn documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Merging_objects_with_same_properties

Comment: it creates a new object without keeping reference to the object, where the merging should happen. only the first work this way.

Comment: Yeah... That's what I wrote in my answer... If they want to merge into a new object.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is `Object.assign()`

Try this:

```
obj["myKey"] = Object.assign(obj["myKey"], addKeys)
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: The left side assignment is not needed. The first argument is modified. Like, pass-by-reference style.

Comment: if the OP wants to keep the object structure as laid out, the left-side assignment is needed. Otherwise, you're creating a brand new object that loses its nest.

Comment: I really don't think that is true.